# Is there a term for this class of measure-like functions?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I am investigating functions $\mu$ with the following property: Let $X$ be a set. Then $\mu : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ (where $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real line) satisfies:

1. $\mu(Y) \geq 0$ for all $Y \subseteq X$.
2. $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.
3. For any $Y_1,Y_2,\dots \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, we have that:
   $$
   \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Y_k\right) = \sup_k \mu(Y_k)
   $$

I can't seem to find any resources regarding functions of this kind, and I would like to know if there there is a particular name for functions like this.

Comment: For any $A$ we get $\mu (X) =\mu (A)$ or $\mu (A^{c})$ (by taking $Y_1=A$ and $Y_n=A^{c}$ for $n>1$. If $\mu$ is finite this implies that the space is trivial in the sense every set has measure $0$ 0r $\mu(X)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm It doesn't follow that $\mu$ takes only two values. Take for instance $\mu(Y) = \sup{Y}$, where $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$ (and setting $\mu(\emptyset) := 0$). $\mu$ is not trivial even if restrict ourselves to $Y \subseteq X$ for some finite $X$.

Comment: If $\mu$ is a finite measure the  it is trivial.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sure, but I am not asking for $\mu$ to be a measure.

Comment: Any non-negative integrable function is of the form $c1_A$ where $A$ has finite measure and $c$ is a  constant.